# T-SQL UPDATE slow, fast when preceded by PRINT

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I'm trying to remove duplicates from a list of names and email addresses. The last statement of my script is an UPDATE that takes much longer than it should - I've never actually waited for it to finish. If I place a PRINT 'anything'; statement directly in front of it, it returns instantly. Same situation with or without the WHILE() loop.

This is a simplified version that I hope illustrates the issue. I'm actually making a Table-Valued Function so I can't just leave the PRINT in there. What effect could PRINT possibly be having?

SQL Server 10.50.4033 (2008 R2)

```
DECLARE @duplicate_names TABLE (
    dnDuplicateKey int,
    dnPrimaryKey int,
    PRIMARY KEY (
        dnPrimaryKey,
        dnDuplicateKey
    )
);

DECLARE @matches TABLE (
    mFirstKey int,
    mSecondKey int,
    PRIMARY KEY (
        mFirstKey,
        mSecondKey
    )
);

--Find Email matches
INSERT INTO @matches
SELECT DISTINCT
    f.elKey,
    s.elKey
FROM
    Emails f INNER JOIN
        Emails s
    ON f.elEMail = s.elEMail;

--Find name matches
INSERT INTO @matches
SELECT
    f.NameKey,
    s.NameKey
FROM
    Names f INNER JOIN
        Names s
    ON f.Name = s.Name
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            @Matches
        WHERE
            mFirstKey = f.NameKey
            AND mSecondKey = s.NameKey
    )

--Condense duplicate matches
--  1 = 2,
--  2 = 1,
--  3 = 4,
--  4 = 3
--to
--  1 = 2,
--  3 = 4
INSERT INTO @duplicate_names
SELECT
    mSecondKey,
    MIN(mFirstKey)
FROM
    @matches
GROUP BY
    mSecondKey;

--Condense chained matches
--  1 = 2,
--  2 = 3,
--  3 = 4
--to
--  1 = 2,
--  1 = 3,
--  1 = 4
WHILE(@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
    UPDATE
        d
    SET
        d.dnPrimaryKey = f.dnPrimaryKey
    FROM
        @duplicate_names d INNER JOIN (
            @duplicate_names f INNER JOIN
                @duplicate_names s
            ON f.dnDuplicateKey = s.dnPrimaryKey
        ) ON d.dnDuplicateKey = s.dnDuplicateKey
    WHERE
        d.dnPrimaryKey <> f.dnPrimaryKey;
```

Comment: But of course the PRINT statement is causing @@ROWCOUNT to return 0 which skips the WHILE() loop. But I've seen this run quickly in other contexts and I just let the PRINT thing red-herring me.
Now it appears to be the difference between a table variable (@Table) and a temporary table (#Table). If I dump the results into a temp table before running the UPDATE, it returns quickly. But I can't use a temp table in a Table-Valued Function so I'll need to take a different tack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yes, it was just a performance difference between a table variable and a temp table. For the interested, here's how I resolved it without using a temp table. It's still slower than the first method but since I can't use temp tables in Table-valued Functions, it's the only option I see.

```
DECLARE @duplicate_names TABLE (
    dnDuplicateKey int,
    dnPrimaryKey int,
    PRIMARY KEY (
        dnPrimaryKey,
        dnDuplicateKey
    )
);

DECLARE @matches TABLE (
    mFirstKey int,
    mSecondKey int,
    PRIMARY KEY (
        mFirstKey,
        mSecondKey
    )
);

--Find Email matches
INSERT INTO @matches
SELECT DISTINCT
    f.elKey,
    s.elKey
FROM
    Emails f INNER JOIN
        Emails s
    ON f.elEMail = s.elEMail;

--Find name matches
INSERT INTO @matches
SELECT
    f.NameKey,
    s.NameKey
FROM
    Names f INNER JOIN
        Names s
    ON f.Name = s.Name
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            @matches
        WHERE
            mFirstKey = f.NameKey
            AND mSecondKey = s.NameKey
    );

--Expand orphaned matches (for which no reciprocal version exists).
WHILE(@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
    INSERT INTO @matches
    SELECT DISTINCT
        f.mFirstKey,
        s.mSecondKey
    FROM
        @matches f INNER JOIN
            @matches s
        ON f.mSecondKey = s.mFirstKey
    WHERE
        s.mSecondKey <> f.mFirstKey
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                @matches d
            WHERE
                d.mFirstKey = f.mFirstKey
                AND d.mSecondKey = s.mSecondKey
        );

--Condense duplicate matches
--  1 = 2,
--  2 = 1,
--  3 = 4,
--  4 = 3
--to
--  1 = 2,
--  3 = 4
INSERT INTO @duplicate_names
SELECT
    mSecondKey,
    MIN(mFirstKey)
FROM
    @matches
GROUP BY
    mSecondKey;
```